# iOS / Android app huge in MBs

Tags: android, ios, file

I'm creating a mobile application in iOS and Android. My customer has a requirement that all the required data will be always available to the application so I must include them in the bundle. It needs to be operable offline.

The problem is that the data I need to have available are more than 300MBs and in some cases more than 500MBs.

What problems will I face during iOS application approval process and android approval process?

Right now I even can't install the app on my Android (Desire HD) ( The app has a been set in the manifest file to install in the sd card, not the internal memory ).

Any suggestions?

Comment: Why not download the data on first start instead of including it in the bundle? The user is presumably on-line to even be able to install the app in the first place.

Comment: We prefer to have it in the bundle so as to keep the best user experience. If the first experience the user has when opens the app is to wait for one hour to load the data, he won't be happy.

If he waits for one hour when downloading the app, he won't think negative. It is mostly a marketing issue.

Also we would like to keep our servers low in bandwidth usage. 

Will we have any problems with such big apps?

Comment: Is there no way to have the content streamable, even today 300-500MB is still excessively large for an application. Having initial content in the bundle and streaming more content in the background would be a much better overall experience.

Comment: Well, if it's not an option... I know for sure that Apple restricts downloads over cellular connections to 50MB. So your app won't even download if the user isn't on WiFi. =/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On Google Play you have a 50 MB restriction on your application, if you need to make it larger than this you can use an [`Expansion File`](http://developer.android.com/google/play/expansion-files.html). These files supports up to 2GB of data.

You should of course take every measure to compress and optimize your data before finishing your application and not just throw everything in there simply because you can.

Answer (score 2):

Any application over 50MB in the Apple App Store must be downloaded over wi-fi only. It cannot be downloaded over a cellular (over the air) connection.

2GB is the current limit in the Apple App Store. I've downloaded iOS apps up to 700MB.

Answer (score 2):

Here are a few pointers to help you out:

1. There are two options to upload app on Google Play: 
   a) Google Play Max Upload size : 50 MB
   b) App Extension Files: Two in number with 2GB each
   c) Refer to Link: http://developer.android.com/distribute/googleplay/publish/preparing.html#size
2. Apple App Store: Max size is 2GB.
3. My MAIN suggestion to you is to divide the modules of your app into parts which include an "Install time Must-Have" component and a second component which the user can download immediately after the installation. This will neither decrease the User Experience nor will it increase the app size by a huge amount. :)

Comment: Ok. So for Apple I will probably not have any problem.

About Android now. Is there any way to unzip the App Extension Files in my desired path in the SD Card? Or do they unzip where the Android likes?

Comment: Read the "Storage Location" section from http://developer.android.com/google/play/expansion-files.html

Comment: Also, as per my earlier suggestion, even if the Apple App store allows a larger file size still it'll be better if you can divide the app into different and distinguishable modules w.r.t. what the user needs immediately after installation and what the user needs at a later point in time.

Comment: The problem is that I don't know what the user will need right after the app download. It depends on what will intrigue his interest and choose to display :) . If he chooses hotels he needs the data from hotels. If he chooses beaches he needs the data from beaches... etc

Comment: From your previous comment, it looks as if you are trying to save the complete search DB on the client. If this is the case then you need to revisit some standard client-server models.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it's a problem *per se*. The limit on iOS (as far as I know) is 2Gb and you're well under that. I understand that the limits on Android are similar (but I don't know for sure).

Having said that, such a huge app does not necessarily make a great user experience. Are users going to want to use so much scarce space on their device? How long are you users going to be happy to wait to download updates to your app?

Even if allowed, it's probably worth trying at least one of these:

- Zipping the data and uncompressing on first launch
- Restructing the data so it takes less space (potentially non-trivial)
- Storing only the "common set" of data and requiring an Internet connection to query the rest

Answer (score 0):

> If the first experience the user has when opens the app is to wait for
>   one hour to load the data, he won't be happy.

Yes, and he will be super happy by downloading 500 MB from Play or other sources? 
Thats more negative.

Even if you publish it somehow,I don't think it's a good idea to let your users download a 550+ MB apk file, as it'll take up a lot of internal storage and it's difficult to update when you have to download that massive file again.

Instead, create a smaller apk file that downloads the optional 500 MB data to the memory card. That way you can easily update the application and it's the most flexible for you, too.